# Autoplay youtube video on hover/mouseover

Tags: jquery

I am trying to play the youtube video for auto play when the iframe tag is on focus.  Tried the following but it is not working. Error with my jquery?
I want to add &autoplay=1 to the src of iframe when it is focus.

Html :-

```
<div class="vid-wrapper" >
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" id="video1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bxgorUGjCIw?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen scrolling="auto" ></iframe>
</div>
```

Css :-

```
.vid-wrapper{
width: 100%;
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
height: 0;
z-index:-20;
}
.vid-wrapper video, .vid-wrapper iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index:-1;
}
```

Jquery :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#video1").mouseenter(function(){

  $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("src") + "&amp;autoplay=1");
 });

$("#video1").mouseleave(function(){
  var src= $(this).attr("src");
  var arr_str = src.split("&amp;");
  $(this).attr("src",arr_str[0]);
  });
});
```

Any help?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't really want to change the `src` attribute, but to use [youtube's api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) for that:

> The snippet will **not** work due to cross-origin problems (specifically in stackoverflow) but the code works.

```js
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'M4Xrh8OP1Jk'
  });
}

$(document).on('mouseover', '#player', function() {
  player.playVideo();
});
$(document).on('mouseout', '#player', function() {
  player.pauseVideo();
});
```

```html
<script src="//www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="player"></div>
```

Here is a working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rurc8rb9/

Comment: It is not working.  See https://www.carbonfiberco.com/ for the video.  It is full screen embed

Comment: It is working. https: is missing with google youtube api in the above code

Comment: I applied above code to the website but it is not working !

Comment: Please see https://www.carbonfiberco.com/  You tube video is just above footer of home page.

Comment: 1. You have a problem with the jQuery (note the `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function` error in your console). you can use `jQuery` instead of `$`. It will fix that problem. 2. I don't see any element in you html with `id=#video1`, so your code code inside `youtube2.js` will do nothing.

Comment: TypeError: $ is not a function
 

$(document).on('mouseover', '#pnpdiv', function() {

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote. Change the `$` to `jQuery` inside your code.

Comment: what exactly not working? Where exactly is the code in my example inside your website?

Comment: ok, got your problem. you changed `player` to `pnpdiv` but you missed the `YT.Player('player'`. You need to change that to `pnpdiv` too.

Comment: Will appreciate if you can also vote-up the answer (now you have enough reputation for that). Thanks!

Comment: Sure ! I will !