# Play Youtube video when hover image

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using : Carousel

```
  <div class="item active">
    <a href="xxx"><picture>
      <source media="(max-width: 900px)"  srcset="imagecat1/mobileview_scene.jpg" style=" max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        display: block;">
  <img src="imagecat1/normal_scene.jpg" alt="banner" style="z-index:1" class="img-fluid">
</picture></a>
  </div>
```

Above is my "carousel" image , everything works fine.

But i wanted to do is , when hover to the "image" show youtube links , any idea how should i do it ?

Tried :

> using this method
>   (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseover)

not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Autoplay youtube video on hover/mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060030/autoplay-youtube-video-on-hover-mouseover)

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want.

Just replace `URL HERE` with the URL you want to display. You might want to use a method other than the built-in `alert`, just replace it in the `onmouseover` attribute of your `<a>` tag.

```html
<div class="item active">
    <a href="xxx" onmouseover="alert('URL HERE')"><picture>
      <source media="(max-width: 900px)"  srcset="imagecat1/mobileview_scene.jpg" style=" max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        display: block;">
  <img src="imagecat1/normal_scene.jpg" alt="banner" style="z-index:1" class="img-fluid">
</picture></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply , the code works , but what i want is that 
When hover on the image , show youtube video ( not just link )

Comment: Change the `onmouseover="alert('URL HERE')"` to `onmouseover="window.location='URL HERE'"`

Comment: thanks , but is there any ways to straight play the video using iframe ?

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to look at YouTube integrations for that.

Comment: any idea on this ? cant find any youtube integrations

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls